# Using . to retrieve value in a Struct

Tags: c, struct

I recently began using structs while coding in C, and end up frequently passing them around, however I find the arrow (->) notation of retrieving variables very messy, and rather inconvenient to use.

Is there any parameter I should give a function, and/or lines I could write at it's top such that it would be able to use the dot (.) notation instead, while still being able to edit the original struct?

I've put all my problem solving skills to the test, and tried Google, but I haven't seen anything yet. I considered a struct with a Struct in it, which should work, but seems messy. I could return the struct after each method, but that is obviously also a bad idea.

Any help appreciated from the masters!

Comment: "I find the arrow notation of retrieving variables very messy, and rather inconvenient" - I laughed out loud. Is `(*obj).member` better, seriously?

Comment: Solution of your problem is to write some codes using both notations then you will see how convenient it is to use `->`.

Comment: No need to be condescending. I don't think OP knew that's the other choice.

Comment: Ah, no, I was just typing out "Data->var" out a few hundred times, and wanted to use "Data.var"

I know that I can dereference it first and use the dot notation, but I forgot to mention it, sorry.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger What is ridiculous is not the fact that one does not know the other options. That's not a problem. But this is like crying that "I don't want to use the + sign for adding numbers"...

Comment: @Corrosive Supposing you were writing C++ (which the tags you've used state you're not), if you passed a reference to the struct to your function, you would use the structure reference operator (.) to change the original struct's fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access by deferencing the pointer, with the dot, but I don't think it is more comfortable:

```
typedef struct tStruct
{
  int a;
};

void func(tStruct *st)
{
  // these two lines are valid
  int b = st->a;
  int c = (*st).a;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with the pointer to member operator `->`. It's part of the language. You just need to get used to it.

Comment: The truth is always harsh. I guess I am being pretty unreasonable.

Comment: @Corrosive; yes notation can take a while to get used to: Music, Knitting Patterns, Combinatorial Mathematics also have their learning curves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you have pointer to your structure S:

```
struct S *myStructure;
```

you can change struct fields using `.`, just you need to dereference pointer first:

```
(*myStructure).field_a = 10;
```

As you can see, it is easier just to type `->` instead.

**Please note** you can use `.` directly on the structures (but not on pointer to structures):

```
struct S myOtherStruct;
myOtherStruct.field_a = 20;
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I knew that already, sorry, but I was hoping for a way to not have to dereference it every time.

Comment: Sure, just use the `->` operator. :)

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted local reference with the ability to change an argument.  Usually, these are conflicting requirements but there is a case, rarely, for passing the struct by value and returning the modified struct as a result.

```
struct s_tag myfunction( struct s_tag s, <other args> )
{
     ...use and modify s
     return s;
}
```

Then the caller can use `mystruct = myfunction(mystruct, <other args>);`.

This makes sense if myfunction does enough computation with s that the cost of copying s is outweighed by the savings by not having to use or share a CPU register with a pointer to mystruct. As I said, "rarely."

That pattern also useful when the performance cost is irrelevant, but you want to use the same function to either modify a struct object, or to use another object as a template for producing a new object with `mystruct = myfunction(template, <other args>);`.